# Firestore backup for documents with timestamp format ID

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database and I try to backup it.

I try to use [firestore-backup](https://github.com/steadyequipment/node-firestore-backup) or [firestore-backup-restore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore).

But **it doesn't work because in one collection I use documents with timestamps IDs** (in this format: 2018-10-19T12:30:40.066Z). Other collections backup fine.

I get this message:

```
The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
   const firestore = new Firestore();
   const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
   firestore.settings(settings);
With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects.
So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
// Old:
  const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
// New:
  const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
  const date = timestamp.toDate();
Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior.
In a future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
Backing up Document '/ttt/2018-10-19T12:30:40066Z'
(node:36336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to create backup path for Document '2018-10-19T12:30:40066Z': RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at FirestoreBackup.backupDocument (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firestore-backup\dist\firestore.js:228:15)
    at C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firestore-backup\dist\firestore.js:210:25
    at C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firestore-backup\dist\utility.js:36:14
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:36336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:36336) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So, is it possible to backup Firebase collections with IDs in timestamp format?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore has an officially supported data export feature, see [export and import data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

Here's an example showing how to run export operations on a schedule: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have changed the timestamp ID to a custom format (2018-10-19T12-30-40-066Z, replacing : and . with -).

This custom format is compatible with the backup.